# How to control user role on Front-end React JS - MERN Application

Tags: reactjs

MERN APP (MongoDB, Express, ReactJS, NodeJS) - on back-end i control the logged user with token and give access to user based on role.

Question is: How to control role of user on front-end (ReactJS) if the user is admin or client?

Ex: 
If user is logged I send a token from backend to frontend and I could control Routes something like this if the user is logged in:

```
if(token){                                //if user is logged
  <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
     <Products/>                          //Products Page
  </Route>
}else{
  <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
     <Page1 />                          //AnyPage
  </Route>
}
```

I want to give access to Users Page only for admin users:

```
if(token && role === 'admin'){                                //if user is logged and role is admin
  <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
     <Users />                          //Users Page
  </Route>
}...
```

I could control this thing on backend, I just want to take any other idea about this issue on frontend.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generally on the right track. That kind of pattern (detecting logged in and/or role status and conditionally rendering components) are generally called "protected routes".

You could do something like this:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({showRoute, ...props}) => {
  if (showRoute) {
    return <Route {...props} />
  } else {
    // return null to simply not render the route if not logged in
    return null;
    // or you could return <Redirect to='/foo' /> to send them elsewhere
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;

  return (
    <Router>
      <ProtectedRoute showRoute={isLoggedIn} path="/dashboard" component={Users} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Or, maybe there are cases where you want to render one version of a component or the other depending on if they're logged in. You could use a `<Switch>` for that to make sure you only render one component (and not both if they are logged in)

```
const App = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute showRoute={isLoggedIn} path="/dashboard" component={LoggedInDashboard} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={LoggedOutDashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Now, something that is very important: **you still need to authenticate every API call or user action on the backend**. It makes for a good user experience to conditionally render components based on some state, but it is *very very insecure*. Remember that anyone with React devtools installed can read and write to React app state at will, so they could simply toggle `isLoggedIn` to `true` or make themselves an "admin" role. **Every API request should be authenticated with a secure token.** Perhaps you know all of that already but it really bears repeating.

Edit: you can get even more streamlined by using React context to have routes that "just know" whether the user is logged in or not (or whatever) and render appropriately:

```
const userLogin = React.createContext(false);

const LoggedInRoute = (props) => {
  const showRoute = useContext(userLogin);

  if (showRoute) {
    return <Route {...props} />
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [userLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <userLogin.Provider value={userLoggedIn}>
      <Router>
        <LoggedInRoute path="/dashboard" component={Users} />
      </Router>
    </userLogin.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I could control with token if user is logged in and render component if it is logged in, the question was how to control on reactjs if user is logged in and which role that user has('admin' or 'simple user')

Comment: if you want to find out what role the user has, just have the backend pass that data along with the token

Comment: @besartm okay. Then what happens when a malicious user manually sets their role to "admin" and gains access to privileged functionality?

Comment: If a user manually set role to 'admin', the only thing what can see is some buttons, or nav links that are suppose to be present only for admin, I could control everything on backed not showing data for that nav links if a user is not admin.

Answer (score 3):

[Interactive example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hellman-7fc7i)

What I would do in such situation:

1. When user signs in, API should return their info, including permissions. Store that info in state.
2. Create a function, `checkUserPermission(user = { roles: [] }, permission)`. This function takes `user` object, `permission` string (i.e. `"route.admin"`, `"component.Authenticate"`) and should return true or false depending on user's access level. That will be one place which decides if current user is allowed to do this or that. It can consist of simple property check (`if (user.role === 'admin')`) or something more complex (look at example).
3. Create `SecuredRoute` component which is a wrapper around `Route` but takes `user` and `permission` parameters and redirects away if user can not see this route.
4. Use `checkUserPermission` function to conditionally render links or components.
5. As already mentioned in other answer, API must do it's own permission checks on every request because hiding things on UI side won't stop malicious and knowledgeable user

---

```
//src/utils/checkUserPermission.js
export default function checkUserPermission(user = { roles: [] }, permission) {
  const allowAccessForRoles = {
    "route.admin": ["admin"],
    "route.authenticated": ["user", "admin"],
    "route.home": ["*"], //means "Any role"
    "component.Authenticate": ["*", "!user", "!admin"], //Any role except user and admin
    "component.BecomeAdmin": ["user"],
    "component.LogOut": ["user", "admin"]
  };

  //If we don't have such permission in list, access denied for everyone
  if (!Array.isArray(allowAccessForRoles[permission])) {
    return false;
  }

  //Check if any of user's roles explicitly denies access
  for (const role of user.roles) {
    if (allowAccessForRoles[permission].includes("!" + role)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //If list of allowed roles contains '*', access allowed for everyone
  if (allowAccessForRoles[permission].includes("*")) {
    return true;
  }

  //Check if any of user's roles allowes access
  for (const role of user.roles) {
    if (allowAccessForRoles[permission].includes(role)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

//src/SecuredRoute
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import checkUserPermission from "./utils/checkUserPermission";

const SecuredRoute = ({
  user,
  permission,
  redirectTo = "/",
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const allowed = checkUserPermission(user, permission);

  if (allowed) {
    return <Route {...rest} render={() => children} />;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: redirectTo,
            state: { from: location }
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default SecuredRoute;

//src/App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SecuredRoute from "./SecuredRoute";
import checkUserPermission from "./utils/checkUserPermission";

const AdminPage = () => <div>Admin page is open for admins</div>;

const AuthenticatedPage = () => (
  <div>Authenticated page is open for users and admins</div>
);

const HomePage = () => <div>Home page is open for everyone</div>;

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">    
        <div className="Nav">
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Go to Home Page</Link>
          </div>
          {checkUserPermission(user, "route.authenticated") ? (
            <div>
              <Link to="/authenticated">Go to Authenticated Page</Link>
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {checkUserPermission(user, "route.admin") ? (
            <div>
              <Link to="/admin">Go to Admin Page</Link>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div className="Controls">
          {checkUserPermission(user, "component.Authenticate") ? (
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setUser({ roles: ["user"] })}>
              Become authenticated
            </button>
          ) : null}

          {checkUserPermission(user, "component.BecomeAdmin") ? (
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setUser({ roles: ["admin"] })}>
              Become admin
            </button>
          ) : null}

          {checkUserPermission(user, "component.LogOut") ? (
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setUser()}>
              Log out
            </button>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div className="Main">
          <Switch>
            <SecuredRoute user={user} permission="route.home" exact path="/">
              <HomePage />
            </SecuredRoute>
            <SecuredRoute
              user={user}
              permission="route.authenticated"
              path="/authenticated"
            >
              <AuthenticatedPage />
            </SecuredRoute>
            <SecuredRoute user={user} permission="route.admin" path="/admin">
              <AdminPage />
            </SecuredRoute>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that the best way could be: For simple User show components only if there is the token (if there is a token there is a logged user), and for admin routes/components  to make a request on backend and check if this logged user has admin permission

Comment: @besartm you cant make requests to backend during rendering. You receive info about user, including roles, during authentication process and then cache it in memory until user signs out or token expires. And use that cached info to determine what parts should be rendered. Also, as was mentioned in other answer, hiding things on frontend is not a security measure, it's just UX thing. Backend must do it's own checks on every request to secured endpoints.

Comment: I tried this, and also have full control of user in backend it works perfect, the only problem is that, If I catch on memory token and user-role, that role on this memory could be edited. So for example if logged user is simple cant see route /users which shows all users, if this user change on catch memory role to admin, the only thing that user see is Nav Link or button for users which send to route /users, but this user cant see users because I control it on backend if this logged user is admin.

Comment: @besartm can't understand your problem. On UI you should get user role (admin/not) at the moment they authenticate and cache it until end of session. On backend you check token for each request, pull user data from DB and decide if they have permissions or not.